# Throw new Exception in Finally Block always called

Tags: vb.net

I have weird problem. 
It's best presented in code:

```
Try
        <CODE>

Catch ex As Exception
        TPETrace.writeToLogFile("C3NetWrapper.SendToC3 exception: " & ex.ToString())
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If bRetValue Then
            TPETrace.writeToLogFile("Com1")
        Else
            TPETrace.writeToLogFile("Com2")
            Throw New Exception("Error")
        End If
    End Try
```

Ok, so no matter if it will be Try or Catch, when my Finally block is called, and bRetValue = true, my line "Com1" will be called as expected, and then during debuging it will go straight to "End If" line... but when I am trying to go next line it's going back to Throw New Exception line (without even calling "Com2") line.

It's weird behavior, Is Throw New Exception always called inside Finally block?

Comment: When you say "*but when I am trying to go next line it's going back to Throw New Exception line (without even calling "Com2") line*" you are refering to when `bRetValue = False`, is that the case? It's not clear for me.

Comment: You are getting misleading information from the debugger, it places the yellow highlight wrong.  It *looks* like it will execute, but that doesn't actually happen when you continue stepping.  There is a highly technical reason for that, but much more important is that this code is fundamentally broken.  Never throw an exception in a finally block, it *replaces* the active exception.   The real exception gets lost so you can't find out anymore what actually went wrong.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I didn't recognize that throw is never raised.
Also I know that it shouldn't be written that way, but that's old solution which is working by some time, and we don't want to change much there.